# Creating rule for two cells equaling same value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a rule that will turn cells A through D red if cells C and D equal 0 or less.

I know how to make the rule with just one cell equaling 0, but would like to make it conditional on both equaling zero.[image: Image of cells in google sheets]

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you indicated in your table which rows should be red.  For example, what do you want to happen for row 14 (question marks)?  What about if one is zero and one is blank or two blanks? Also add some negative value in the example data if that is part of the question. 

Answer (score 1):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A1:D`:

```
=isnumber($C1) * (max($C1:$D1) <= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting

```
=AND($B1<=0,$C1<=0)
```

[image]